# bulkCopy.WriteToServer() not throwing exception when no data is copied

Tags: c#, sql, sqlbulkcopy

I'm trying to copy a `DataTable` into a destination table on Sql Server. I use the following code. I know that `bulkCopy.WriteToServer()` is an atomic (all-or-nothing) function. But when nothing has been copied, I would like to know!

```
try
{
    using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConn.ConnectionString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity | SqlBulkCopyOptions.UseInternalTransaction))
    {
        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "MyDestinationTable";
        bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
        convertSuccess = true;
    }
}
catch
{
    convertSuccess = false;
}
```

I have seen the case that nothing was copied into "MyDestinationTable" but I was unaware of it because my `convertSuccess` flag returned `true`. Is there a way to know if the bulkCopy has done its job?

Comment: without being very familiar with the bulkcopy function, could you not just do a row count on the targeted table before and after?

Comment: @user2366842 that's what I also thought. But what if the table was not already empty?

Comment: Then you'd just grab the number of rows in the table before, and compare it with the total after...if the number after is greater, the bulk copy would've succeeded, unless this is a table where rows might be added/deleted by other processes, in which case this might not work as expected...although like i said, I'm not overly familiar with bulkcopy, so there might be a better way to do this.

Comment: @user2366842 this makes sense and I will eventually do this if I did not find a better solution.

Comment: Why not just check if `dt.Rows.Count > 0`? if rows are in your data source either they will be inserted or WriteToServer will fail with a exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify your *[NotifyAfter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.notifyafter(v=vs.110).aspx)* property and then handle the *[SqlRowsCopied](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.sqlrowscopied(v=vs.110).aspx)* event after x amount of rows.

```
static void Main() {
    try {
        using(SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConn.ConnectionString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity | SqlBulkCopyOptions.UseInternalTransaction)) {
            //Event handling
            bulkCopy.SqlRowsCopied += new SqlRowsCopiedEventHandler(OnSqlRowsCopied);
            bulkCopy.NotifyAfter = 50; //Put your rowcount here

            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "MyDestinationTable";
            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
            convertSuccess = true;
        }
    } catch {
        convertSuccess = false;
    }
}


private static void OnSqlRowsCopied(object sender, SqlRowsCopiedEventArgs e) {
    Console.WriteLine("Copied {0} so far...", e.RowsCopied);
}
```